# Boundary conditions for a differential equation using sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to specify boundary condition for the differential equation.

```
# *y"= 900(y - 1 + 2x) ; y(0)=5, y(2)=10*

from sympy import *
x=symbols('x')
y, g = symbols('y g', cls=Function)
diffeq = (Eq(y(x).diff(x, x) - 900*y(x) + 900, 1800*x),y(0):5,y(2)=10)
A=dsolve(diffeq, y(x))
print A
```

But it is showing the error

```
diffeq = (Eq(y(x).diff(x, x) - 900*y(x) + 900, 1800*x),y(0):5,y(2)=10)
                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The boundary conditions are passed to `dsolve` as a dictionary, through the `ics` named argument.

Thus:

```
from sympy import *
x=symbols('x')
f=symbols('f', cls=Function)
dsolve(Eq(f(x).diff(x,x), 900*(f(x)-1+2*x)), f(x), ics={f(0):5, f(2):10})
```

You can paste the last line to [sympy live](http://live.sympy.org) to verify that it works. The answer is:

f(x) = C1*e^−30x + C2*e^30x − 2x + 1

Comment: But it still shows the constants, C1 and C2 inspite of specifying the boundary conditions.

Comment: Maybe it's a sympy bug? You'd need to read more in the documentation. In any case, the workaround is simple: do the substitutions at the boundaries, and pass to a linear system solver to get the constants.

Comment: @KubaOber can you explain that better?

Comment: On Sympy 1.8 the constants C1 and C2 are solved correctly